# Drupal 7 #ajax callback on form submit

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

Hello I have created a custom form added a # ajax callback on form submit

```
    $form['hotel_book_form']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Check Availability'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => "list_rooms",
      'wrapper' => "replace_hotelbook_div",
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );
```

and I have added this wrapper as suffix to the form

```
    $form['hotel_book_form'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Book Hotel'),
    '#weight' => 5,
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_hotelbook_div"></div>',
  );
```

but when I click on form's submit button the page gets simply reloaded and the ajax callback function does not fire.

Comment: I have the same problem now, did you fit it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't actually wrapped the element, you've inserted an empty `<div>` immediately before it.

You need to use `#prefix` *and* `#suffix` to wrap an element in HTML:

```
...
'#prefix' => '<div id="replace_hotelbook_div">',
'#suffix' => '</div>'
```

Comment: Thanks Clive, but I have tried that still the same thing is happening. The page gets reloaded on submit instead of calling the ajax function.

Answer (score 1):

this isn't quite consistent with the behaviour you describing, but you are adding an element to an array:

`$form['hotel_book_form']['submit'] =`

then you are replacing the entire array. So you need to change:

`$form['hotel_book_form'] =`

to

`$form['hotel_book_form']['someother_suitable_value'] =`

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be simply on your rendered html
For instance i got the same issue because my ajax call was fired on a button click rendered on a form as below

```
 <button class="mapping_remove">Remove Mapping</button>
```

Once i made sure the type of the elment is a button my form stopped submitting

```
<button type="button" class="mapping_remove">Remove Mapping</button>
```

NOTICE : I added type="button" as an attribute

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with CTools form than try to add this to the top of your form or form alter hook:

```
if ($form_state['rebuild'] == TRUE) {
  ctools_include('wizard');
  $form = $form_state['wrapper_callback']($form, $form_state);
}
```

Here is an explanation: https://drupal.org/comment/5112672#comment-5112672